# Locate features along route - differentiate between real intersection and just touching bufferd zone Arcgis 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, line, arcgis-10.4, route

[Image: Case1 and Case 2](https://ibb.co/i9zawF)

I have a polyline (also as route) representing a pipeline (green), a polyline representing the axis of a power line (black) and a polygon representing the allowable distance between powerline and pipeline (brown).

I use locate features along the route to identify the intersection of pipeline and powerline polygon to see where the pipeline is too close to the powerline. Result is a table with from x m to y m (FMEAS TMEAS) pipeline is in the polygon. 
BUT: 
If the pipeline is parallel to the power line the minimum distance (polygon) is compulsory.
If the pipeline intersects the powerline it is no problem.

How can I differentiate automatically between case 1 (not a real intersection with the powerline) and case 2 (a real intersection with the powerline)?

Comment: You could clip the green pipeline to the polygon and explode multiparts. Add a field called 'Intersects', then use a simple Select by Location to find those that intersect the powerline, update the Intersects field to 'Y' for these and switch selection to find those that don't, update the Intersects field to 'N' for these. This will Give you sections of pipe within the minimum distance polygon that intersect or do not.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I continued with "locate features along routes"  with the pipeline as route to get the FMEAS und TMEAS for each part along the whole pipeline.